# How to test header, axios.defaults.headers, with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, http-headers

In my application, I have a middleware to check for a token in a `req` in order to access private routes:

```
const config = require('../utils/config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  let token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token. Authorization DENIED.' });
  }

  try {
    let decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.JWTSECRET);
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is invalid.' });
  }
};
```

In order to send a `req` with the correct token in my program's Redux actions, I call the following function, setAuthToken(), to set the auth token:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = token => {
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'];
  }
};

export default setAuthToken;
```

My Redux action using axios and the setAuthToken() function:

```
export const addPost = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    //set the token as the header to gain access to the protected route POST /api/posts
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const res = await axios.post('/api/posts', formData, config);

    // ...

  } catch (err) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

How can I write a test to test setAuthToken()? The following is my attempt:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import setAuthToken from '../../src/utils/setAuthToken';

describe('setAuthToken utility function.', () => {
    test('Sets the axios header, x-auth-token, with a token.', () => {
        let token = 'test token';

        setAuthToken(token);
        expect(axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token']).toBe('test token');
    });
});
```

The following is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

Looking up this error, it sounds like it is because there is no `req` in my test. If that is the case, how can I re-write my test to send a `req`? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `console.log(axios)` in your test file to check if it is being mocked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my case, there is a `__mocks__` directory in my project. There is a mocked `axios`. More info about `__mocks__` directory, see [Manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock)

`__mocks__/axios.ts`:

```js
const axiosMocked = {
  get: jest.fn()
};
export default axiosMocked;
```

When I run the test you provide, got the same error as yours. Because mocked `axios` object has no `defaults` property. That's why you got the error.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import setAuthToken from './setAuthToken';

jest.unmock('axios');

describe('setAuthToken utility function.', () => {
  test('Sets the axios header, x-auth-token, with a token.', () => {
    let token = 'test token';
    setAuthToken(token);
    expect(axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token']).toBe('test token');
  });
});
```

So I use [jest.unmock(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestunmockmodulename) to use the real `axios` module instead of the mocked one.

After that, it works fine. Unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64564148/setAuthToken.test.ts (10.913s)
  setAuthToken utility function.
    ✓ Sets the axios header, x-auth-token, with a token. (5ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.828s
```

Another possible reason is you enable [automock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#automock-boolean). Check both command and `jest.config.js` file.